# Redshift unload script

Tags: shell, amazon-redshift

I have a script that has multiple redshift unload statements

```
UNLOAD('SELECT * FROM test.products WHERE product_name LIKE \'%20160912%\'') 
TO 's3://test-bucket/products/20160912/prod_'
CREDENTIALS 'XXXX'
DELIMITER AS '|' parallel off;
```

There are multiple such statements. I want to parameterize the date and pass in the date when I run this script. How can I do this?

The script would be like this

```
UNLOAD('SELECT * FROM test.products WHERE product_name LIKE \'%${DATE}%\'') 
TO 's3://test-bucket/products/${DATE}/prod_'
CREDENTIALS 'XXXX'
DELIMITER AS '|' parallel off;
```

Is there a way to replace ${DATE} when I run the script. I know there is PREPARE in Redshift but my thought is it cannot work with the Unload statement. Another option is to write a shell script and have the shell script call this SQL script. But is there an easier way to just pass in the parameter when running the SQL script from the command line.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

There is no ability to pass parameters to an `UNLOAD` command.

The `PREPARE` statement works only for `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

You will need to insert the desired parameters into the command *prior to* sending it to Redshift. This could be done from a bash script like this:

```
psql ... "UNLOAD (SELECT * FROM ... WHERE date = '`date +%Y%m%d`')..."
```

This would substitute the current date (`date +%Y%m%d`) as part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to an unload statement using a bash script. Call 'psql' for your Redshift instance from an edge node accessing the Redshift database cluster and use the '-v' argument.

For example: In a Bash Script that is calling the SQL Script:

```
$> curr_date=$(date +%F)
$> select_of_unload_stmt='SELECT * from myTable where column like \'$curr_date\''
$> psql -h <HostName> -p <Port_Number> -d <Database_Name> -U <User> -v RS_Script_Unload_Stmt="$select_of_unload_stmt" -v date_var="$curr_date" -f <Script_Containing_RS_Unload_Query.SQL>
```

Within the SQL Script, you can reference the passed variable as :RS_Script_Unload_Stmt. So you can create the Unload in your SQL Script as:

```
UNLOAD (:RS_Script_Unload_Stmt) TO 's3://test-bucket/products/:date_var/prod_' CREDENTIALS 'XXXX' DELIMITER AS '|' parallel off;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the necessary changes in the script itself rather than to include something in `unload` statement.

What I did is:

`aws s3 mv s3://[bucket_name]/"$file_name".csv000 s3://[bucket_name]/"$file_name$from_date".csv`

What it does is:

1. Populate the bucket on s3 with the file that your `unload` statement generates.
2. Rename (`move`) the file appending the date/timestamp to the file name.

Here, `$from_date` is a variable, initialised as `date --date='1 days ago' +'%Y-%m-%d'`;